# the code works no matter which text I type

Tags: python, discord.py

Wow... Hello, I'm back here after two days. (Thank you to the person who helped me last time..)
First of all, this code works in the direction I want.
However, there is a problem.

This bot's command is "!공지". However, this bot sends me a message because the code works no matter what chat I write... I want to make it work only when I write "!공지"

```
    @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user: 
        return
    if message.content.startswith("!공지"):
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
    i = (message.author.guild_permissions.send_messages)
    if i is True:
            notice = message.content[4:]
            channel = client.get_channel(927233433489526904)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="*브리핑*", description="\n――――――――――――――――――――――――――――\n\n{}\n\n――――――――――――――――――――――――――――".format(notice), color=0x00ff00)
            embed.set_footer(text="-C0de")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.imgur.com/UDJYlV3.png")
            await channel.send (embed=embed)
 
    if i is False:
            await message.channel.send("{}, 당신은 관리자가 아닙니다".format(message.author.mention))
```

Comment: Indentation is important in python. You need to put the code you want to execute on the command within the same indentation as the  `if message.content.startswith("!공지"):` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the code to exit if the user's message doesn't start with "!공지" then add

```
if message.content.startswith("!공지"):
    await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
else:
    return
```

This will exit the function if the message does not start with those characters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this:

```
i = (message.author.guild_permissions.send_messages)
if i is True:
```

Since anyone who writes something has that permission, `i` will always be true.

I guess what you want to do is to indent those two lines, so it is inside the if-block that checks the command.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `i = (message.author.guild_permissions.send_messages)` line to the same indentation as the if conditional, while also initializing your `i` before the if-else statement:

```
i = False
if message.content.startswith("!공지"):
    await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
    i = (message.author.guild_permissions.send_messages) # set only in condition.
else:
    i = False
```

When inserted in code:

```
    @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user: 
        return
    i = False # initialize i
    if message.content.startswith("!공지"):
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
        i = (message.author.guild_permissions.send_messages) # set only in condition.
    else:
        i = False
    if i is True:
        notice = message.content[4:]
        channel = client.get_channel(927233433489526904)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="*브리핑*", description="\n――――――――――――――――――――――――――――\n\n{}\n\n――――――――――――――――――――――――――――".format(notice), color=0x00ff00)
        embed.set_footer(text="-C0de")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.imgur.com/UDJYlV3.png")
        await channel.send (embed=embed)

    if i is False:
        await message.channel.send("{}, 당신은 관리자가 아닙니다".format(message.author.mention))
```

This should let your code properly branch based on the command